# input type image URL value pass through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form with number of input type images. I need to replace the webpage location to url of the image when a user clicks any image.

form is like,

```
<form action='free.php' id='freeForm' method='post' autocomplete="off">
<?
for($j=1;$j<=5;$j++)
{
?>
<a href="<?=$url;?>" class="anchor-url"> <input type="image" src="<?=$img;?>" /></a>
 <?
 }
 ?>
 </form>
```

$img and $url values from database.

My jquery is like,

```
$("#freeForm").submit(function()
    {
            var Form = { };
            Form['inputFree'] = $("#inputFree").val();

                    Form['freeTOS'] = '1';



              $('.anchor-url').click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
              alert($(this).attr('href'));
           });


            $.post('processFree.php', Form, function(data)
            {
                    if(data == "Success")
                    {
                            $("#FreeErrors").html('').hide();
                            swapToPane('paneSuccess');
                            return;
                    }

                    swapToPane('paneFree');
                    $("#FreeErrors").html(data).show();
            });

            return false;
    });
```

Now I am getting 'http://au.yahoo.com' when i click each image. But I want to replace 'http://au.yahoo.com' with URL of each image. How can I pass the PHP variable $url to this form?
Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *should* work, if I understood what you were asking for correctly and though I haven't tried it. Basically you bind the click event to each image, and on click it replaces the window location with the value in the `src` attribute of the `input` element being clicked on.

```
$('input[type=image]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.replace($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

**EDIT**

First you should add a class name to your anchor elements:

```
<form action='free.php' id='freeForm' method='post' autocomplete="off">
<?
for($j=1;$j<=5;$j++)
{
?>
<a href="<?=$url;?>" class="anchor-url"> <input type="image" src="<?=$img;?>" /></a>
 <?
 }
 ?>
</form>
```

Your JS:

```
$('.anchor-url').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.replace($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Notice how I added a class to the anchor links. This can be named almost anything. This gives you the ability to  select for those elements with that classname only with jQuery using the $('.any-classname') selector.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I need to replace the window location with 'a href value' of each input image. I think your code will replace the location with 'image src' value.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Updating my answer.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for that. I have updated my code as above. But $('.anchor-url').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
is not working. I couldn't see any alert msg.

Comment: Are you sure you added `class="anchor-url"` to your anchor links?

Comment: yes, am sure. Because When I use var href= $('.anchorurl').attr('href'); alert(href); , alert message always shows the first url value of image. So I think click function is not working.